# Java REST api http method type to call stored procedure that executes sql delete query

Tags: java, sql-server, rest, stored-procedures, jersey

I am writing RESTful web services using Java(Jersey). I have to call a function which calls a SQL server stored procedure using `CallableStatement` .This stored procedure executes multiple SQL delete query. Here what will be HTTP method type (GET, PUT, DELETE etc) for this and is using `CallableStatement` the right way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think both are not related. You need to look at what is business functionality you are achieving with this call based on that you need to decide which HTTP method suits to it.

The HTTP methods are used in REST for more REST Consumer to understand the functionality at high level.  There is no technical restriction like if you use POST you should do only addition/insertion.

Since you are doing delete operations, I think you should go for 'DELETE'